# Insert javascript file in cshtml page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'd like in an `.cshtml` page, insert an `.js` page.

I tried this :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyFile.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

No problem with the same code in the `shared/_layout.cshtml` (in the header section)

When I execute the application, this file is not present in the source code (not include).

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the response httpCode? Look using a web developer tool like Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tool in Chrome.

Comment: Is the script block included in your source code?

Comment: The response is correct but the js is not in

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/MyFile.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I used Areas, then I tried several level of ../../.. but same

Comment: @Kris-I did you try "/scripts/MyFile.js" without ~?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (assuming you are using Razor templating in MVC3). The only way this would not work is if the path to your script is wrong.

Comment: yes with razor :) The .js is in the same folder than the others. But the others are called from /shared/_layout.cshtml

Comment: The `~/` in the Url means that the path should be relative to the root of your solution - is this definitely using the right path?